# Issue in generating keystore file with password

Tags: android, flutter

I've gone through a few tutorials on how to export a flutter app but I can't seem to get the keystore thing. In the tutorials after they enter the command the option of enter password comes up but I just get a list of commands, like [image: this]

Answer (score 0):

That's because the command you entered isn't right. I understand you are using `""` to put folder names which have spaces in it. But the way you have used them will change the meaning of whole command. That's what the `command prompt` is complaining saying `Iilligal option:`

Keep your entire command including the folder paths in a single double quote pair.
Use it like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\keytool -genkey -v -keystore E:\nush\key.jks -storetype JKS -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias key"
```

Comment: it gives me this error: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: just check if the path to `keytool.exe` and `E:\nush` are correct. Especially check if `E:\nush` folder is available

Comment: Okay so I searched around and there is no key.jks file anywhere